# Dowload files from Azure Blob Storage with French filename

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-blob-storage, french

I am using Java SDK for connection to Azure Blob Storage:

```
@Bean
@SneakyThrows
public CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer(CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount) {
    return cloudStorageAccount
            .createCloudBlobClient()
            .getContainerReference(sourceContainerName);
}
```

During the download process, I am taking listBobs and the necessary `CloudBlockBlob`.

[image]

It exists in the list of blobs. Then I try to download it:

```
blob.downloadToFile(path);
blob.delete();
```

And it fails with error:

```
Method threw 'com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException' exception.
The specified blob does not exist.
```

The interesting fact is that when I rename blob to remove the french accent letters it works as expected. But I can't resolve it from server side. I can't copy to blob with a filename without french accent letters since every oberation on `CloudBlockBlob` fails with 404 HTTP code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test with `azure-storage` 5.0.0 and it could download the file with `associé.txt` name. Maybe you could try with my code or provide more information to let me have a test.

```
    final String storageConnectionString ="connectionstring";

    CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

    CloudBlobClient serviceClient = account.createCloudBlobClient();

    CloudBlobContainer container = serviceClient.getContainerReference("test");
    container.createIfNotExists();

    File file = new File("E:\\Test");
    for(ListBlobItem item : container.listBlobs()){
        CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) item;
        File f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" +cloudBlob.getName() );
        cloudBlob.downloadToFile(f.toString());
        System.out.println(cloudBlob.getName()+" success download");
    }
```

[image]